# Counting the number of characters, words and number of lines present in a text input such that it takes input until user types the word 'END'

Tags: c, loops

I have written code for this. But the problem I am facing is that my program doesn't takes more input after I wrote any of one letters of word **END**. I want it to stop only when it encounters the word **END**, not only single letter. The code that I have tried is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    char ch[100];
    int nl = 0, nw = 0, nc = 0;
    printf("Enter lines of text (enter END to complete)\n");
    scanf("%[^END]", ch);
    for(int i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(ch[i] == '\n'){
            nl++;
            nw++;
        }
        else if(ch[i] == ' ' || ch[i] == '\t'){
            nw++;
            nc++;
        }
        else{
        nc++;
        }
    }
    printf("Character = %d, Words = %d, Lines = %d\n", nc, nw, nl);
}
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Re-read the documentation for `scanf()` and what a `%[^...]` format means.

Comment: Make a loop read the entire strings, using `" %[^\n]"` in `scanf`, then use a function like `strstr` to find if the string contains the substring `END`, if it does you can end the loop. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line `scanf("%[^'END']", ch);`, you can't do this in scanf `%[^'END']`.

Rather you can ask the user to input `EOF` character instead of `"END"` and then you can put that `EOF` into condition to terminate the process.

Take a look at this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    int nl = 0, nw = 0, nc = 0;

    printf("Enter text (enter EOF to complete)\n>");
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == '\n') // If C has a newline character then it means there's a new line in text.
            nl++;
        if(c == ' ' || c == '.') // We are assuming that these characters can be delimiters b/w words.
            nw++;
        nc++; // Every Input is a character.
    }
    printf("Character = %d, Words = %d, Lines = %d\n", nc, nw, nl);
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** There could be problems with this code while deciding no. of words. But if `input` isn't that complex. It'll not give any logical error. You can advance it to get the accurate no. of words from `input`. Most of the words in a paragraph are separated by `.`, `,` or `_`.

If you really want to go with the `"END"` word, try this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int main(void)
{
    char input[BUFFER_SIZE] = {'\0'}, *cptr = NULL;
    int word_count = 0, line_count = 0, char_count = 0, i = 0;

    printf("Input text\nInput END to terminate>\n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &input[i]);
        i++;
        cptr = strstr(input, "END");
    }
    while(cptr == NULL);
    char_count = i - 3; // Excluding END word.
    for( ; i != 0; i--)
    {
        if(input[i] == '\n') // If C has a newline character then it means there's a new line in text.
            line_count++;
        if(input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '.') // We are assuming that these characters can be delimiters b/w words.
            word_count++;
    }

    printf("Character = %d, Words = %d, Lines = %d\n", char_count, word_count, line_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was not doing the program as a file handling problem. And, cant we make "END" as a word that will tell the program to stop taking inputs,

Comment: @fortnightlearner "*cant we make "END" as a word that will tell the program to stop taking inputs*" - you certainly can, just not with pattern matching in `scanf()`.  You will have to handle this manually, by reading the input char-by-char until you detect the sequence `'E' 'N' 'D'`, or word-by-word until you detect a single word `"END"`, or line-by-line until you detect a single line `"END\n"`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you write the code for taking input.

Comment: We can make END to stop taking input. I'm editing my answer, take a look at the updated answer. @fortnightlearner

Comment: And I strictly warn you about the counting of words. Here, you need to follow the delimiter pattern, i.e. separate each word with either ```.``` or ```<space>```. Otherwise, you'll get wrong count of words.

Comment: @fortnightlearner One more thing, asking the user for the EOF doesn't makes your problem as a file-handling problem. There's a lot in file-handling problems, not just EOF. EOF is an integral value(-1).